# How can I determine if a URL redirects?

Tags: perl, http, redirect, groovy

If I have a URL (eg. http://www.foo.com/alink.pl?page=2), I want to determine if I am being redirected to another link.  I'd also like to know the final URL (eg. http://www.foo.com/other_link.pl).  Finally, I want to be able to do this in Perl and Groovy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Perl:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $request  = HTTP::Request->new( GET => 'http://google.com/' );
my $response = $ua->request($request);
if ( $response->is_success and $response->previous ) {
    print $request->url, ' redirected to ', $response->request->uri, "\n";
}
```

Comment: s/GET/HEAD/. With google.com it doesn't seem any faster, but try it with microsoft.com...

Answer (score 8):

Well, I know nothing about either Perl or groovy, so I'll give you an another from an HTTP point of view, and you'll have to adapt.

Normally, you make an HTTP request, and you get back some HTML text along with a response code.  The response code for Success is 200.  Any response code in the 300 range is some form of a redirect.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to James's answer - sample HTTP session:

```
$ telnet www.google.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.google.com


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.it/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: ##############################
Date: Thu, 30 Oct 2008 20:03:36 GMT
Server: ####
Content-Length: 218
```

Using HEAD instead of GET you get only the header. "302" means a temporary redirection, "Location:" is where you are redirected to.

Answer (score 3):

A quick & dirty groovy script to show the concepts -- Note, this is using [java.net.HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

In order to detect the redirect, you have to use `setFollowRedirects(false)`.  Otherwise, you end up on the redirected page anyway with a `responseCode` of 200.  The downside is you then have to navigate the redirect yourself.

```
URL url = new URL ('http://google.com')
HttpURLConnection conn = url.openConnection()
conn.followRedirects = false
conn.requestMethod = 'HEAD'
println conn.responseCode
// Not ideal - should check response code too
if (conn.headerFields.'Location') {
  println conn.headerFields.'Location'
}

301
["http://www.google.com/"]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl you can use [LWP::Useragent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) for that. I guess the easiest way is to add a `response_redirect` handler using `add_handler`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for 301 redirects.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $request  = HTTP::Request->new( GET => 'http://google.com/' );
my $response = $ua->request($request);
if ( $response->is_redirect  ) {
    print $request->url . " redirected to location " .  $response->header('Location') .  "\n";
}
```