# Recording url redirections

Tags: python, ruby, perl, url, bit.ly

Does anyone know whether there is a simple way to record all urls on a path of url redirections?

For example: the url: (url 1) redirects to (url 2) which redirects to (url 3).

I would like to write a script that takes an input the string (url 1) and returns (url 2) and  (url 3).

Is there a simple way to do this (ideally without using javascript)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251532/how-can-i-determine-if-a-url-redirects

Comment: This might help: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142745

Answer (score 1):

in python:

```
import requests

url = 'http://google.com'

r = requests.get(url)

urls = [e.url for e in r.history]+[r.url]
```

then you get:

```
>>>urls
[u'http://google.com', u'http://www.google.com/']
```

it works only if the redirection are in the http layer (the 30x range)

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'net/http'

def redirect_tracker(url)
  paths_array = [url]
  code = nil

  begin
    response = Net::HTTP.start(URI.parse(url).host){|http| http.request Net::HTTP::Head.new(url) }
    code = response.code.to_i
    paths_array << url if url = response['location']        
  end while (301..303).include?(code)

  return paths_array
end

redirect_tracker('http://google.com') 
# => ["http://google.com/", "http://www.google.com/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a `$response` from LWP,

```
my @request_uris;
while ($response) {
   unshift @request_uris, $response->request->uri;
   $response = $response->previous;
}
```